# oracle 06502 declaration char(1)

Tags: oracle

i have this ora-06502.

i declared

```
**letter char(1);**
```

And i use this declaration in

```
letter := substr(v_string,1,1);
v_string_bis := letter;
for i in 2..length(v_string) loop
if (substr(v_string,i,1) != letter) then
letter := substr(v_string,i,1);
v_string_bis:= v_string_bis||letter;
end if;
end loop;
```

After i get this ora. 
I know its a problem of length but i how can i replace this char(1) ? by varchar2 ? or should i increase to char(2) for example ?

Any ideas please ?

Thank you

Comment: The database is  UTF8

Comment: Why are you needing to use CHAR?

Comment: "*how can i replace this char(1) ? by varchar2*" - That's not what  the "2" in `Varchar2` actually means :-)

Comment: Have you tried to change the declaration to either `char(2)` or (preferably) `varchar2(2)` ? It seems more likely that it's either complaining about the declared maximum length of `v_string_bis`, or you need `letter` to be `varchar2(1 char)` because it's defaulting to a single byte. Please include sample data that is causing the error, and the full error stack.

Answer (score 4):

You are only putting one character at a time into your `letter` variable, at least in the code you showed, so assuming the error message is identifying that it is one of those assignments that is throwing the ORA-06502 you may just have multibyte characters.

If your DB/session [length semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-B3C74175-7F77-49A6-9CC9-1F6F70F3A69D) are set to `byte` then you're declaring a single-byte variable. You probably just want it to be a single character instead:

```
letter char(1 char);
```

or (as there isn't really any reason to use `char`, even for one character):

```
letter varchar2(1 char);
```

It's also possible that the concatenation onto the `v_string_bis` variable is causing that to exceed its maximum declared length, which could also be a byte/character discrepancy; but as we don't know how that is declared now or how long the source strings are we don't know if that's the case. The error message would point to the line with that assignment if that was the cause though.

---

To demonstrate the difference that specifying the semantics can make:

```
declare
  letter char(1 byte);
begin
  letter := unistr('\00a0');
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4

declare
  letter varchar2(1 byte);
begin
  letter := unistr('\00a0');
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4

declare
  letter char(1 char);
begin
  letter := unistr('\00a0');
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

declare
  letter varchar2(1 char);
begin
  letter := unistr('\00a0');
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```